# ¿como encender Flash de la cámara en uso?

Tags: android

Estoy intentando activar el flash de la cámara. el código siguiente funciona para activarlo, pero en mi caso necesito que permanezca activo cuando se ejecute otra vez la cámara(desde una librería u otra aplicación ) y no se apague o que en la siguiente ejecución de la cámara me aparezca la excepción por “Camara ocupada”

lo estuve pensado ¿se podría cambiar los parámetros de una cámara en ejecución si no tengo la variable de Camera o CameraManager con la que fue ejecutada ?

```
camera = Camera.open(0);
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
```

No puedo usar `CameraManager.setTorchMode()` ya que manejo api menor a 23

Comment: Hola acabo de ver tu pregunta,has intentado Camera2?

Comment: pues use(intente) CameraManager, CameraDevice pero la funcionalidad que me interesa no me sirve para mi api